# Refresh Token with named credentials stopped working

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce

We have a REST integration with a third party system: **OAuth flow with Open ID connect**.
The configuration is the same for over a year now, but recently we realized that the authentication doesn't work anymore when it comes to the second refresh of the access token.

**Auth. Provider** has the default configuration for Open ID connect:

- checked "Send access token in header"
- checked "Include consumer secret in SOAP API Responses"
- unchecked "Send client credentials in header"

[Auth. Provider Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hQqF.png)

(Legacy) **Named credentials** are configured with:

- identity type: Per User
- Authentication Protocol: OAuth 2.0
- Authentication Provider: from above
- Scope: refresh_token full
- checked "Generate Authorization Header"
  [Named credentials screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwFoC.png)

The other end uses WSO2 for user management and has a service provider set up:
**Allowed Grant Types**

- Code
- Implicit
- Password
- Refresh Token
- SAML2
- IWA-NTLM
  **Callback Url**: from Auth. Provider
  checked **Support PKCE 'Plain' Transform Algorithm **
  **Token Issuer**: Default

[Service Provider configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJITj.png)

Now, after the OAuth browser flow, the authentication works fine. If the access token is expired, but the initial refresh token not, the callout is successful.

As soon as the **initial refresh token is expired**, we receive an **Unauthorized** message. Retry isn't successful.

For testing purposes we set the expiry times as follows:

- 60 seconds for the access token
- 120 seconds for the refresh token
  Callout after 90 seconds (access token expired, refresh token not): successful; should receive a new refresh token
  Callout after 180 seconds (access token expired, initial refresh token expired): Unauthorized

I changed the configuration in Salesforce:

1. NC scope: refresh_token
2. Auth. Provider default scope: full refresh_token & NC scope: blank
3. Auth. Provider default scope: refresh_token full & NC scope: blank
4. Auth. Provider send access token in header unchecked
5. NC Scope added "offline_access"
6. Auth Provider select "send client credentials in header" & "Send access token in Header"
7. NC Scope: full refresh_token

Setup New named credentials as per Salesforce Help with same settings.

None of the changes made any difference.

I tested the same from Postman, there it works. So in general we receive a valid refresh token.